# VBscript replaces text but adds blank line

Tags: vbscript

I have the following vbscript to replace text within a file. It does exactly what I want, however it adds a blank line at the end of the file for each pass I make. If I replace 'black' with 'red' and then change 'white' to 'yellow', it has added two blank lines to the end of the text file. Is there a way to change this so it doesn't add lines?

Here's the script:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

strFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
strOldText = Wscript.Arguments(1)
strNewText = Wscript.Arguments(2)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText

objFile.Close
```

p.s. - the syntax is: cscript /nologo replace.vbs InputFile "OldText" "NewText"

Comment: Have you tried `objFile.Write strNewText`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objFile.WriteLine` adds a newline character at the end. You probably need `objFile.Write`

WriteLine will add \r\n (or whatever the system newline is)

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
strText = objFile.ReadAll
```

will read **all** content of the file, including (possibly) a trailing EOL. (.ReadAll <> .ReadLine)

```
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
```

will **add** an EOL. So use

```
objFile.Write strNewText
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
objFile.Writeline
```

To

```
objFile.Write
```